# Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page instead of router admin page

Tags: networking, login, router

I want to change the password of my wifi at home. But until now I didn't succeed.

I've tried a couple of different websites who claim to give me my ip address. They give all the same number combination, but when I copy paste it in to the address bar in my internet browser it keeps loading... and nothing happens.

I checked for another way to find my ip address. I've found online a website explaining everything for windows, so I tried to find the linux alternative for `ipconfig`. It appeared to be `ifconfig` and I found another ip address over there. When I copy that one in to my internet browser's address bar, I get a page about Apache2 that's running... but not the login page from my router as I expected.

Anyone an idea how I can login to my router to change the password?

Comment: Edit your post to include the output of `ip a` and `route -n`, please. The gateway IP is likely to be of your router.

Comment: Or, `netstat -r | grep default`
`default         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan` Where 10.0.0.1 is my default gw(router)

Comment: What if you add http:// before the ip when accessing the page in your browser?